# Putting results of array into a form control

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created an array in VBA in my Access application, and when I run it I get the intended results in the immediate window. What I am trying to do now is to take that array and put it into a form control (possibly a subform dataset?). I do not know how to this though on a multidimensional array. Below is the code that creates my array (it's dynamic, it can contain from zero to 10 results depending on how many records are in the DB.

```
 ' We need to get all of the participants for this engagement (Name, Email, Division and Role)
    strSQL4 = "SELECT tblPerson.Person_FName, tblPerson.Person_LName, tblPerson.Email, tblORD_Division.ORD_Div, tblEngParRole.Role FROM tblORD_Division INNER JOIN ((tblEngagements INNER JOIN tblEngParRole ON tblEngagements.ENG_ID = tblEngParRole.Eng_ID) INNER JOIN tblPerson ON tblEngParRole.Person_ID = tblPerson.Person_ID) ON tblORD_Division.ORD_DIv_ID = tblPerson.ORD_Div_ID WHERE tblEngagements.Eng_ID = " & Me.Eng_ID
    Set rs4 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL4)
    

rs4.MoveLast
rs4.MoveFirst

'Let's retrieve ALL Rows in the rs4 Recordset
varParticipants = rs4.GetRows(rs4.RecordCount)
 
 
Debug.Print "******************************************"       'Column Format only
Debug.Print "Last Name", "First Name", "Email", , "ORD_Div", "Role"
Debug.Print "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
For intRowNum = 0 To UBound(varParticipants, 2)        'Loop thru each Row
  For intColNum = 0 To UBound(varParticipants, 1)      'Loop thru each Column
    'To Print in Table Format, no numbered Fields or Rows
    Debug.Print varParticipants(intColNum, intRowNum),
  Next
  Debug.Print vbCrLf

  Debug.Print "******************************************"     'Column Format only
Next
rs4.Close
Set rs4 = Nothing
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of using a subform on the main form, but again I do not know how to get the array variables to a datasheet.

Comment: Why are you pulling data to an array instead of using that query as RecordSource for a form or report?

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with a subform using the query above. The only issue is that I need the query to filter on a control from the main form (ENG_ID). So right now I have the query as it is above without the where clause. How would I go about that? I have ENG_ID entered into the Link Master Field and Link Child Field. Thanks again.

Comment: HansUp, yes, that is what I did. Added ENG_ID to Master and Child links. I got it working using your suggestion below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access doesn't provide a convenient way to display an array on a form.  Skip the array and use a [form/subform](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b) approach to display your data.

Build a query similar to your current query, but with these two changes:

1. Include `tblEngagements.Eng_ID` in the list of `SELECT` columns.
2. Discard the `WHERE` clause so the query will return all rows regardless of their `Eng_ID` values.

Build a new form based on that query.

Add the new form as a subform to your original form.  On the subform control's property sheet, set the *Link Master Fields* and *Link Child Fields* properties to `Eng_ID`

Then, in operation, the subform should display only those rows whose `Eng_ID` values match the `Eng_ID` of the current row in the parent form.

Comment: Sweet, that was so much easier.